# counting comparisons in optimized bubble sort algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, bubble-sort

As the title says, i need to count how many comparisons i have while sorting a given array with the optimzed bubble sort algorithm.

The problem is, I get 45 as a result, when the output should be 31 (for the array given in the main). I also tried setting the upper bound for the second inner loop to the last index where a comparison was made, but it's not correct still.

`

```
public class Main{
    public static int optimizedBubbleSort(int[] arr) {
        int n = arr.length;
        int comparisons = 0;

        // Set flag for whether the list is already sorted
        boolean sorted = false;

        // Keep looping until the list is sorted
        while (!sorted) {
            sorted = true;
            int lastSwapIndex = 0;

            // Loop through the list and compare adjacent elements
            for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
                comparisons++;
                if (arr[i] < arr[i + 1]) {
                    // If an element is out of order, swap it and set the sorted flag to false
                    int temp = arr[i];
                    arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
                    arr[i + 1] = temp;
                    sorted = false;
                    lastSwapIndex = i;
                }
            }

            // Set the upper bound for the second inner loop to the last index where a swap was made
            n = lastSwapIndex + 1;
        }

        // Return the number of comparisons made
        return comparisons;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = {10, 42, 27, 17, 58, 39, 91, 19, 42, 66};
        int comparisons = optimizedBubbleSort(arr);
        System.out.println("Number of comparisons: " + comparisons);
    }
}
```

`

Comment: Did you step through your code with a debugger? My _assumption_: when the list is finally sorted `while (!sorted)` will still run through everything once more, especially if the last swap occured at the end of the list.

Comment: Your algorithm will not be able to produce 31 as a result, since your algorithm always do a full pass of the array, so the result will always be a multiple of 9. You need to fix your algorithm first.

Comment: The bubble sort algorithm is the opposite of "optimized".

Comment: Are you sure about the result being 31? Anyways you have to move the initialization / declaration of "lastSwapIndex" outside of the while to avoid it being reset to 0. Also if you change the sorting direction from ascending you get 32 comparisons.

Comment: @justhalf The line `n = lastSwapIndex + 1;` prevents exactly that. I assume that's why it's called the "optimized" version.

Comment: @Nelfeal, ah, I missed that. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You are sorting the array in descending order. Your condition `arr[i] < arr[i + 1]` means you swap elements if the second is *greater* than the first, so you place the greater number first. This does indeed do 45 comparisons on the example array you have.

Simply change your condition to `arr[i] > arr[i + 1]` to sort in ascending order, doing 32 (not 31) comparisons instead.